# Node Lambda Using PDF Parsing Library Not Bundling Correctly

Tags: javascript, typescript, aws-lambda, aws-cdk, esbuild

Using the library [pdf.js-extract](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdf.js-extract) though I've tried other PDF parsing libraries and they've all run into similar issues when I try to run them in my lambda (locally they are fine).

My CDK Bundling looks like below (using esbuild)

```
  bundling: {
    minify: true,
    sourceMap: true,
    externalModules: ['aws-lambda', 'aws-sdk', 'canvas'],
  },
```

And this library throws the following error when running

```
"Cannot find module './pdf.worker.js'
```

I can see in their main code they point to the path for that file like so

```
PDFWorkerUtil.fallbackWorkerSrc = "./pdf.worker.js";
```

I'm guessing this is causing the issue because after bundling, there is nothing at that path.

Is there a way I can fix this by bundling this library differently?